# Access request object within validation pipe

Tags: nestjs

I am trying to access to `Request object` from within a `Validation Pipe` in `nestjs`

In order to verify uniqueness of certain fields, I require the `ID/UUID` parameters supplied with `PUT/PATCH` request (not available in the data structure itself)

any idea?

Comment: did you try with custom decorator?

Comment: I don't understand how it is relevant, can you please elaborate  ?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, it is not possible to access the request object at all in a `pipe`. If you need the request you can use a [guard](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards) or an [interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors).

If you are working on verifying uniqueness, that sounds like a part of business logic more than just about anything else, so I would put it in a service and handle the query to the database there. Just my two cents.

## Edit 11/17/2020

After learning way more about how the framework works as a whole, technically it is possible to get the entire request object in a pipe. There are two ways to go about it.

1. Make the pipe `@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })` so that it is [request scoped](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes). This will end up creating a new pipe on each request, but hey, if that's your cup of tea then great.
2. Make a [custom parameter decorator](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators) as custom decorators get completely passed into pipes as they are. Do note, that this *could* impact how the `ValidationPipe` is functioning if that is bound globally, at the class, or method level.

Comment: True, but it is missing all the class-validator strength, and Interceptor are not the solution for transforming the received data

Comment: Well, like I said, it isn't possible to get the request in a pipe. There are ways around that with things like `async-hooks`, but I don't have any knowledge about how. It could also lead to performance hits, so use with caution and make sure to test the difference if you go with that route

Comment: How can you pass it in though once you've defined it as request scoped? You can't do Pipe(reqest) because that is defined in the same as the @Request response that you would usually use for something like this

Answer (score 2):

We can create a Pipe and access request object. We can move further and update the Body as well, if needed.

Following is an example scenario, where `createdBy` field should be added to the Body dynamically. Let's say user details are available from request:

```
// user.pipe.ts
import { Request } from 'express'
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core'
import { Injectable, Inject, Scope, PipeTransform } from '@nestjs/common'

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class UserPipe implements PipeTransform<any> {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) protected readonly request: Request) {}

  transform(value) {
    let email = this.request["user"].email;
    value['createdBy'] = email;
    return value
  }
}
```

We can now use this in controller like this:

```
// someentity.controller.ts

  @Post()
  public async create(
    @Body(SetUserPipe) dto: SomeEntityDto,
  ): Promise<SomeEntity> {
    ....
  }
```